# possible random.multivariate_normal bug when size is too large

Tags: python, numpy

I am confused by the answers I get from `numpy.random.multivariate_normal`:

I have a file of 50 lines of (mean1 mean2 standard_dev1 standard_dev2) and I would like to generate a large number of random points within this probability distribution.

Here is a snippet of the code I am using:

```
data = np.loadtxt(usefile)

# calculate average and standard deviation
gauss_vals = np.array([])

N = 100

for i in range(len(data)):
    mean = (data[:,0][i], data[:,2][i])
    cov = [[(data[:,1][i]**2), 0], [0, (data[:,3][i]**2)]]
    dat_gauss = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, (N,1))
    output_outfile.write(str(dat_gauss) + '\n')
# END
```

When N=100 (or less) the code works and the correct number of lines are generated. However, when N is increased beyond 100 (say to 1000) the code completes but only generates 300 lines, 6 for each line in the infile.

Is this a memory problem or a bug within `random.multivariate_normal`, how do I make this code so I can have N = 1,000,000?

Thanks,

Paddy

Answer (score 0):

The problem mush come from `str(dat_gauss)` if you have a sufficiently large array the result of `str(np.array)` will be something like

```
[[ 0.87660572 -2.36172246]
 [ 1.96780972  8.49576542]
 [ 2.25980567  1.25293228]
 ...
 [ 2.30964954 -8.08709668]
 [ 1.41874824  8.53223703]
 [ 1.13222461  8.97437442]]
```

Therefor you must explicitly write each term of your data in your file or you `numpy.savetxt` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html